# These old answers need some attention

Tags: discussion

[Is it possible to “boost your immune system”](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-it-possible-to-boost-your-immune-system)

Most of the answers seem to be just speculation and opinion. Are they salvageable? Is this question not answerable in its current form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I cleaned it up somewhat.

There were 4 not-so-good answers.

- One was abandoned and unreferenced. I've deleted it
- One was a comment and I've converted it.
- Two are unreferenced. I've put the "unreferenced" disclaimer up, and we should probably fix or delete them after having given the owners reasonable time to fix them
- The rest of the answers seemed acceptable.