# Some old answers on a specific question need attention

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was going to point out exactly what's pointed out on this meta question from six years ago:

[These old answers need some attention](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1506/these-old-answers-need-some-attention)

The following question (still?) has some questionable answers.

[Is it possible to "boost your immune system"?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-it-possible-to-boost-your-immune-system)

I've commented and flagged some of them, but I think all of them have some issues, but not all of them need deletion.

I would delete:

- [David Hedlund's](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/87/11643)
- [Suma's](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/106/11643)
- [user405's](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/626/11643)

I would put a references banner on the following because they don't really explain anything with the references they have:

- [Sklivvz's](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/217/11643)
- [mootinator's](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/625/11643) is close to needing it, so I'm going with "do it".
- [Nick's](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/11183/11643)
- [user11599's](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/42555/11643)

I think the only answer not in need of intervention is [Christian's](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/509/11643), but it could certainly be expanded and worked out further.

Comment: I've dealt with the flagged answers so far, but haven't looked yet at your suggestions here.

Comment: I note: This is the tenth oldest question on Skeptics.SE, from the private Beta! It shouldn't be too surprising the answers don't follow the community standards that have evolved over the years since.

Comment: Just to emphasize Oddthinking's point for users that arrived later on this site, at that point we didn't require references for answers and we didn't require notability for questions. The Skeptics rules as we know them now didn't exist.

Comment: Also for reference: we keep these questions for historical reasons, but there's no need to fix them. Especially there's no need for moderator action if a user merely disagrees with an answer, or thinks it should be different.